# Spring Cosmos - Some requests gives slow response, stucks in Unsafe.park wait for seconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are connecting to cosmos database using azure-spring-data-cosmos library. We are able to receive response in 20ms but for 5% requests (1TPS load) it takes more than 5seconds. Requests stucks in Unsafe.park.

```
container.queryItems(querySpec, options, Store.class)
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We observed it takes time in .collect(Collectors.toList());

```
DirectConnectionConfig directConnectionConfig = DirectConnectionConfig.getDefaultConfig();                  
            cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint(uri)
                    .key(key)
                    .contentResponseOnWriteEnabled(true)
                    .directMode(directConnectionConfig)
                    .multipleWriteRegionsEnabled(true)
                    .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.valueOf(consistencyLevel.trim().toUpperCase()))
                    .preferredRegions(Arrays.asList(preferredRegion.split("\\s*,\\s*")))
                    .buildClient();
```

Why requests goes in wait state ? How to improve this ?

We tried setting maxRequestsPerConnection= 8 or 16. And idleEndpointTimeout = 24hrs. No luck.

Comment: what consistency level? Did you check if the Cosmos RU are enough? are you getting http 429? (you can check that in the cosmos metrics on the azure portal); What responses are you referring, writes or reads?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, I suggest enabling query metrics and response diagnostics in your Configuration.java (or equivalent). The response diagnostics will help debug client side resource issues, and query metrics will help rule out high RU charges, as the cause of your slow response times. From there, you may need to investigate other areas, such as data model, partition key, etc.

```
@Bean
public CosmosConfig cosmosConfig() {
    return CosmosConfig.builder()
                       .responseDiagnosticsProcessor(new ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation())
                       .enableQueryMetrics(properties.isQueryMetricsEnabled())
                       .build();
}

private static class ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation implements ResponseDiagnosticsProcessor {

    @Override
    public void processResponseDiagnostics(@Nullable ResponseDiagnostics responseDiagnostics) {
        logger.info("Response Diagnostics {}", responseDiagnostics);
    }
}
```

See also quickstart sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos/cosmos-quickstart-samples/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/data/cosmos/samples/quickstart/SampleAppConfiguration.java).